# How to do a circular dependency with System.Reflection.Emit

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit

I have a generation framework that can generate dll using system.reflection.emit but have a case that i dont think can be solved with Emit, or atleast i have not figured out to do a minimal repro that shows it is possible.

```
[EntityInterface(EntityKey = "OpenId Connect Identity Resource")]
public interface IOpenIdConnectIdentityResource

{
  
}

[EntityInterface(EntityKey = "OpenId Connect Scope Resource")]
public interface IOpenIdConnectScopeResource<TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectScopeResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectScopeResource<TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectResource<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectIdentityResource

{

   
}
    

[EntityInterface(EntityKey = "OpenId Connect Resource")]
public interface IOpenIdConnectResource<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectScopeResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectScopeResource<TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectResource<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectIdentityResource
{

   
}


[EntityInterface(EntityKey = "OpenId Connect Scope")]
public interface IOpenIdConnectScope<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource> : IOpenIdConnectResource<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectScopeResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectScopeResource<TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectResource<TOpenIdConnectScopeResource, TOpenIdConnectResource, TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource>
    where TOpenIdConnectIdentityResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectIdentityResource
{
   
}
```

creating a normal c# project and implementing the classes below myself compiles fine, howwever i have not been able to set this up with TypeBuilders.

```
  public class OIDCScope : DynamicEntity,
    IOpenIdConnectScope<OIDCScopeResource,OIDCResource,OIDCIdentityResource>
{

}
public class OIDCScopeResource : OIDCIdentityResource,
    IOpenIdConnectScopeResource<OIDCResource,OIDCScopeResource,OIDCIdentityResource>
{

}
public class OIDCIdentityResource : DynamicEntity, IOpenIdConnectIdentityResource
{

}
public class OIDCResource : DynamicEntity ,
    IOpenIdConnectResource<OIDCScopeResource, OIDCResource,OIDCIdentityResource>
{

}
```

Is it possible to generate the above classes, with system.relection.emit that implements that given interfaces without getting a typeloader exception when trying to .CreateType()?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, given the simple proof here:

```
var moduleBuilder = module.Module;

var classA = moduleBuilder.DefineType("TypeA", TypeAttributes.Public
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.Class
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.AutoClass
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.Serializable
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
var classB = moduleBuilder.DefineType("TypeB", TypeAttributes.Public
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.Class
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.AutoClass
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.AnsiClass
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.Serializable
                                                                    | TypeAttributes.BeforeFieldInit);
        classA.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IReference<,>).MakeGenericType(classA,classB));
        classB.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IReference<,>).MakeGenericType(classB, classA));
        var classAType = classA.CreateType();
        var classBType = classB.CreateType();
```

with the following interface

```
public interface IReference<T1,T2>
{

}
```

Either A or B can not be created first due to the reference interface - and typeloader exception is thrown.